# How does engine placement in a Custom Vehicle affect gameplay?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

The most interesting vehicle slot in the game, the Garage, has three different parts: The vehicle construction, the wheels and the engine.

The wheels and the engine have adjustable placement.

[image: The Garage]

Being able to move wheels around makes sense. We can move the wheels more close or apart from each other, and we can make the suspension higher or lower.

However, I cannot figure out what moving the engine can do. I have encountered little changes in gameplay, but I don't know what exactly these changes are and how I can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the engine will change the center of weight.

For example, a rear mounted engine will slightly increase the momentum at a cost of the risk of flipping.

If you have more rear wheel power and you want more speed, a rear wheel engine will give you that because during acceleration the center of gravity moves backward and the rear wheels have more traction with that added weight. Upon hill climbing, this can become an issue if you accelerate too much and flip the vehicle.

Comment: Does changing the wheel size also affect the weight of the wheels?

Comment: yes. same principle but in a much smaller way as the weight is smaller and lower (a little bit of physics). you should configure it depending on vehicle, traction, circuit and driving style